# c# Azure Functions separate html and css

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I'm currently using Azure Functions to generate html pages for an internal system; so it doesn't need to be hosted on web-server for my needs. Iv currently been copying and pasting html into string variable and returning it as a response. However, this means I have to combine CSS and the html into one big long string and its difficult to organise and manage.

Is there way of separating the html and css into separate files and linking it to azure function as response?

Example of structure:

- *\View\HomePage\ HomePage.html, HomePageAzureFunction.cs*
- *\View\Style\Style.css*
- *\View\Javascript\Javascript.js*

Comment: Do you mean you still want to return all 3 files in one response from Azure Function, or return HTML with links to css/js and then have separate calls to retrieve those?

Comment: My feeling is that Azure Functions is not designed to replace MVC app. You better have a client side app (you can host it on Azure CDN or any CDN) and Azure Functions will be your API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there way of separating the html and css into separate files and linking it to azure function as response?

You could leverage [kudu](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2014/03/24/using-kudu-with-windows-azure-web-sites/) or ftp tool to access your azure function files, then add the relevant directories and files (html,css,etc) as follows:

[image]

**run.csx:**

```html
#r "System.Web"

using System.Web;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;

public static HttpResponseMessage Run(HttpRequestMessage req,TraceWriter log)
{ 
    var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    var stream = new FileStream(@"d:\home\site\wwwroot\HttpTriggerCSharp4\view\Home\index.html", FileMode.Open);
    response.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html");
    return response;
}
```

**Note:** The css and javascript files could not be correctly loaded as follows:

```
https://<your-functionapp-name>.azurewebsites.net/<your-HttpTriggerName>/view/style/site.css
```

For this scenario, you may need to add other HttpTrigger endpoints to access the css and javascript files. For me, I would use Azure Blob storage to store the CSS and javascript files, details you could follow [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-storage-explorer). And you could add the css and javascript files in your html file as follows:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://{your-storage-account}.blob.core.windows.net/{container-name}/view/style/site.css">

<script src="https://{your-storage-account}.blob.core.windows.net/{container-name}/view/javascript/site.js"></script>
```